# Stripes ActionBean URL bindings

Tags: javabeans, stripes, urlbinding

I'm trying to set up the [Stripes calculator example application](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/AJAX) using Eclipse. I'm able to run the .jsp on the server, but as soon as I invoke an ActionBean by clicking one of the buttons (such as "add"), I get:
 ActionBeanNotFoundException: Could not locate an ActionBean that is bound to the URL 
[/quickstart/Calculator.action]

This makes sense, because the package directory is set up so Calculator.action is in 
/examples/quickstart/Calculator.

So I figured I could fix the problem by copying CalculatorActionBean.java into the correct folder, outside of the "examples" folder. Same problem. My guess is that the filter is set up so that it only pays attention to files inside the "examples" folder.

How can I set up the directory structure and/or filter to find the ActionBean I'm looking for and bind it to the right URL? Maybe a little explanation on URL bindings would be helpful too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I had named the root directory of my project "examples" and it was parsing out that name in the directory structure. I renamed my project and it works now.